# MYSQL show case value even if the case does not exist in dababase

Tags: mysql, case

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/027e1e/19

sample dataset here:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `mode` varchar(10),
  `value` int(3)
);

INSERT INTO `test` (`mode`, `value`) VALUES
  ('xx-a', '1'),
  ('xx-a', '1'),
  ('xx-c', '2'),
  ('xx-d', '3');
```

SQL query here:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN mode LIKE '%-a' THEN 'a'
WHEN mode LIKE '%-b' THEN 'b'
ELSE 'c' 
END AS channel,
IFNULL(SUM(value), 0)
FROM test
GROUP BY channel
```

When the value '%-b' does not exist in the database, it returns only 2 rows with 'a' and 'c'.
I need it to return 3 rows for all a, b, and c where b shows 0.

Thanks

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and edit your question

Comment: @nbk thank you for the info, will work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to use `union all`:

```
select 
    'a' channel, 
    sum(case when mode like '%-a' then value else 0 end) sum_value
from mytable
union all select 
    'b', 
    sum(case when mode like '%-b' then value else 0 end) 
from mytable
union all select 
    'c', 
    sum(case when mode not like '%-a' and mode not like '%-b' then value else 0) 
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
 SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN mode LIKE '%-a' THEN 'a'
        WHEN mode LIKE '%-b' THEN 'b'
        ELSE 'c'
    END AS channel,
    IFNULL(SUM(value), 0),
    IFNULL(COUNT(value), 0)
FROM database   GROUP BY channel   
UNION   
SELECT 'b',0,0 FROM dual
    WHERE not exists 
    (SELECT 1 FROM database WHERE mode LIKE '%-b')
```